# How To Pass Arguments To new Class & Define Variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the plugin function in the original PHP class named My_Widget_Admin which i have copied over from a plugin to my theme, but get **Fatal error Too few arguments to function My_Widget_Admin**

Here is the code i added in my theme :

```
class Custom_Admin extends My_Widget_Admin { 

    function item_select() {

        // Code
    }

}

$new = new Custom_Admin;

$new->item_select();
```

I think it has something to do with this code from the plugin :

```
    private $_instance;

    private $_widget_object;

    function __construct( $instance, $widget_object ) {

        $this->_instance = $instance;

        $this->_widget_object = $widget_object;

        $this->form();

    }
```

I need to pass these 2 arguments $instance, $widget_object to the new function Custom_Admin.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Passing arguments to a `constructor` must be done when the class gets instantiated. This is done with the `new` keyword.

```
class Custom_Admin extends My_Widget_Admin { 

    function item_select() {

        // Code
    }

}

$new = new Custom_Admin($instance, $widget_object);

$new->item_select();
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i get undefined variable. Does this mean i have to copy over the plugins constructor function function __construct( $args, $instance, $widget_object )

Comment: Actually this means the two variables which are passed to the constructor are not available in the scope of the instantiation. Custom_Admin extends My_Widget_Admin so you don't need to copy because the constructor is inherited.

Comment: @Michelle it seems, that your php knowledges are poor. You just put `$instance` or `$widget_object` here `$new = new Custom_Admin($instance, $widget_object);`. you should defined them before calling them somwhere. it means, you should have somewhere above that line something like `$instance=something;`,`$widget_object=something`. But I'm not suggest you to doing anything. Hire somebody, who knows what to do

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the use of  $this in the plugin and may need to be used in the theme. @SamvelAleqsanyan if you have a answer which actually works, please post it as a complete answer.